# Fastest ways to filter for values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, filter

A similar dataframe can be created:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["nodes"] = list(range(1, 11))
df["x"] = [1,4,9,12,27,87,99,121,156,234]
df["y"] = [3,5,6,1,8,9,2,1,0,-1]
df["z"] = [2,3,4,2,1,5,9,99,78,1]

df.set_index("nodes", inplace=True)
```

So the dataframe looks like this:

```
        x        y        z
nodes
1       1        3        2
2       4        5        3
3       9        6        4
4       12       1        2
5       27       8        1
6       87       9        5
7       99       2        9
8       121      1        99
9       156      0        78
10      234      -1       1
```

My first try for searching e.g. all nodes containing number 1 is:

```
>>> df[(df == 1).any(axis=1)].index.values
[1 4 5 8 10]
```

As i have to do this for many numbers and my real dataframe is much bigger than this one, i'm searching for a very fast way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried something that may be enlightening

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.set_index("A", inplace=True)
df_no_index = df.reset_index()
```

So set up a dataframe with ints right the way through. This is not the same as yours but it will suffice.

Then I ran four tests

```
%timeit df[(df == 1).any(axis=1)].index.values
%timeit df[(df['B'] == 1) | (df['C']==1)| (df['D']==1)].index.values
%timeit df_no_index[(df_no_index == 1).any(axis=1)].A.values
%timeit df_no_index[(df_no_index['B'] == 1) | (df_no_index['C']==1)| (df_no_index['D']==1)].A.values
```

The results I got were,

```
940 µs ± 41.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.47 ms ± 7.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.08 ms ± 14.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.55 ms ± 51.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Which showed that the initial method that you took, with index seems to be the fastest of these approaches.  Removing the index does not improve the speed with a moderately sized dataframe

Comment: Okay thank you very much! So i already implemented the fastest one^^